# Sort list of int non-consecutively

Tags: c#, sorting

Given a `List<int>` like `{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 }`, I would like to obtain `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 }`. I have a working code but I would like to find a more elegant/neat way to handle this problem.

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
var sortedList = new List<int>();
var set = new HashSet<int>();

while (list.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var l in list)
    {
        set.Add(l);
    }
    sortedList.AddRange(set);

    foreach(var s in set)
    {
        list.Remove(s);
    }
    set.Clear();
}

// sortedList -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: What if you have a list like 1,1,1,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,10 ?

Comment: It should then be 1,3,4,5,10, 1,4, 1

Comment: Since you have working code I'd suggest [codereview.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *Linq*; first we turn the initial `list` into groups

```
  {1, 1, 1}
  {2, 2, 2}
  {3, 3, 3}
  {4}
```

Then enumerate items in these groups - `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}` and flatten them: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}`. Let's extract it as a method:

**Code:**

```
private static List<int> MySort(IEnumerable<int> list) {
  var groups = list
   .GroupBy(item => item)
   .Select(chunk => new {
     value = chunk.Key,
     count = chunk.Count()
   })
   .OrderBy(item => item.value)
   .ToArray();

  int maxCount = groups.Max(group => group.count);

  return Enumerable
    .Range(0, maxCount)
    .SelectMany(i => groups
       .Where(chunk => chunk.count > i)
       .Select(chunk => chunk.value))
    .ToList();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
List<int>[] tests = new List<int>[] {
  new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 },
  new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10 },
};

var demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{string.Join(", ", test),-35} -> {string.Join(", ", MySort(test))}"));

Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4        -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10    -> 1, 3, 4, 5, 10, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4
```